# Purpose of 'Attachment Directories' field in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield, photos, attachments, directory

In QGIS, what does the 'Attachment Directories' field in the QField section of Configure Project do, and where has the Photo Naming tag gone?

Using QGIS 3.26.3 and QField 2.5.2-6, I've been trying to get photos to go in some place other than DCIM in the project folder in QField, with no success, so one question is what does the 'Attachment Directories' field in the QField section of Configure Project do; its initial setting is DCIM, but changing it in various ways appears to do nothing, and the photos go into DCIM.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the main question is that the attachment directories section specifies a folder that gets copied to/near your export folder, so that, for example, if you replace 'DCIM' with '../Stuff' (no quotes, forward slashes even on windows), and there is a folder called 'Stuff' that is an 'aunt' of the folder your project file is in, that folder will be copied to your export directory, as sister to the project folder.  The copying is dumb, anything in the folder will be copied with no regard to its being used in the project.

The relationships are a bit confusing in that a sister to the project .qgz will become a subfolder of the project's export folder, so to get a sister to the project's export folder, you need an 'aunt'.

The section says 'attachment directories' in the plural, but I have not yet found a syntax for specifying more than one that works (semicolons didn't seem to work, but testing this stuff is error-prone)

However, QField itself seems unable to use such directories: https://github.com/opengisch/QField/discussions/3726#discussioncomment-4333049

Comment: This is the reason for the One question per Question policy highlighted in the [Tour], so that Answers that don't answer all questions can't be generated.